# MVC Bootstrap Issues With Form-Horizontal class

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, model-view-controller, bootstrap-4

I'm a newby to VB/Net MVC and BootStrap. Can anyone advise why the Form-Horizontal class is not getting applied in the following code. This is nested in an @Using (Html.BeginForm()) tag

```
@<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Team</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(True, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
    @Html.HiddenFor(Function(model) model.id)


    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.Name, htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "col-sm-2 control-label "})
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Name, New With {.htmlAttributes = New With {.class = "form-control"}})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Name, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.Stadium, htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "col-sm-2 control-label"})
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Stadium, New With {.htmlAttributes = New With {.class = "form-control"}})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Stadium, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.League_id, "League_id", htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "col-sm-2 control-label"})
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("League_id", Nothing, htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "form-control"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.League_id, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.Visited, htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "col-sm-2 control-label"})
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Visited, New With {.htmlAttributes = New With {.class = "form-control Checkbox"}})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Visited, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Current result is]

Any help gratefully accepted.

Comment: There is no form-horizontal class in Bootstrap 4. Read the docs on [Form layout](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#layout)

Comment: Happy Days. All sorted. Many Thanks for the update.